# server request stuck on waiting

Tags: javascript, postgresql

when I am requesting for my server :

```
    POST http://localhost:3005/users HTTP/1.1
    content-type: application/json
    {
       "username":"cookie123",
       "bio": "I am a cookie"
    }
```

it's stuck on waiting

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be a blank line between the HTTP headers and the HTTP body.

Also the first line, since you are not making a request to a proxy, should  should use the [origin-form](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.3.1), not the full URL. The hostname should be specified with the `Host:` header.